# Grouping in RDLC Report

Tags: c#, report, rdlc

I am producing a kind of accounting report. It is a balance sheet actually.

What I have:

1. An *AccountGroupCategory* table. For example, Assets or Liabilities
2. A *AccountGroup* table. For example, Current or non-current assets.
3. A *Account* table. For example, Short-term investment

In terms of relationships, the first one is the father of the *AccountGroup* and latter is the father of the *Account*.

I need to display them as the following:

- Assets (which is of course the first item above)
- Current Assets (the second item)
- Short-term investment (the last one)

  Record Two...
  Record Three...   etc.

I hope I could make the concept clear.

My Problem: How can I create such a report in rdlc?

Thank you,

Comment: Could you upload a sample format of your report . a screen shot of excel or anything. so that it will be more clear